# Apache Flex 4.9

Tags: apache-flex, flexmojos, flex-mojos

I have just mavenized the Apache Flex 4.9 SDK. Now, how can I build my application with maven?
Does anybody have an example pom-File for this?
Is there a flex-mojos version out yet, which is working with this flex version? Or are there any alternatives?

Btw.: My application is running, when I build it with Flash Builder 4.7.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the guy currently in charge of continuing the development of Flexmojos.

I have to say, that RIAstars comment is not correct. I created the Mavenizer for usage with an updated version of Flexmojos and it is reported to work quite nicely together with it. Unfortunately I haven't released FM6 yet as I wanted to have it stable first. Because of this you have to fetch my github fork from https://github.com/chrisdutz/flexmojos ... I was planning on merging my changes back to the public repo as soon as Atlassian finally sets up our GIT repo at https://flexmojos.atlassian.net

I am currently working on making FM6 a parity release to the FM5 but with the difference that it works with the fdks generated by the mavenizer. What is true, is that I will not add any new features to FM, such as native Air bundling for mobile devices and support for falcon.

This is because we have already started the development of a purely Apache maven plugin that should replace FM one day. The main reason is the enormous effort you have to invest in maintaining a plugin that builds all FDKs starting with Flex 2.x and eliminating some design problems that were causing a lot of support traffic on the mailinglist.

So I would say: Yes you can use the Mavenizer to mavenize your FDKs and then you use FM6 to build your apps with it because that's what I created them for :-)

Answer (score 0):

FlexMojos as it is will no longer be developed for future versions of Flex. As such I don't think you'll be able to use it with your mavenized version of Flex (but I might be wrong; I'm not exactly certain how it all works).

However the current maintainer of FlexMojos (Christofer Dutz) is working on a brand new Flex/Maven plugin. So for future versions you should be able to use that. Unfortunately to my knowledge this projects is far from finished.

As an alternative there is [GradleFx](http://gradlefx.org/) which is a plugin for [Gradle](http://gradle.org/). You can set up an Apache Flex SDK dependency simply like this:

```
dependencies {
    flexSDK group: 'org.apache', name: 'apache-flex-sdk', version: '4.9.0', ext: 'zip'
}

repositories {
    add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = 'Apache'
            addArtifactPattern 'http://apache.cu.be/flex/4.9.0/binaries/[module]-[revision]-bin.[ext]'
    }
}
```

Personally I find Gradle much easier to work with than Maven. (Disclaimer: I am a contributor to the GradleFx project, but I only became one because I loved it so much).

Comment: As I commented in my reply ... I built the Mavenizer for FM6 so it will definitely work together. I just decided not to add the Mavenizer to FM but to donate it to Apache because this is where I think the furute music will be playing.

Comment: @chrisdutz Didn't know you were out here on stackoverflow too. I'd 've kept my mouth wisely shut if I'd 've known ;)

Comment: Well I have to admit that I was notified about this topic by guys on the flex-dev mailinglist so I woudn't have noticed the thread without them ;-)